# jQuery .mousedown/up cursor move causes fail

Tags: jquery, mousedown

I want to make divs on my site 'depress' when clicked by adding a slight margin to the top. I thought .mousedown/up would be good for this except for the case where the user moves the mouse off the div mid-click. In this case, the dive stays depressed and will move down even further from its original position every time it happens

http://jsfiddle.net/dLwovpd9/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#foo').mousedown(function() {
        $('#foo').css('margin-top', '+=2px')
    })

    $('#foo').mouseup(function() {
        $('#foo').css('margin-top', '-=2px')
    })
})
```

How do I stop this from happening? Is it better to use a different method than .mousedown?

Comment: you must add boolean parameter. then you can use either mousedown or mouseup (use only 1) or onclick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I altered your code so that the `mousedown` event stores the depressed button in a variable and altered the `mouseup` event to work on the entire document. It will check to see if there is a depressed button and if so it will undepress the button.

http://jsfiddle.net/2mynzftt/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var depressedButton = null;

    $('#foo').mousedown(function() {
        depressedButton = $(this);
        depressedButton.css('margin-top', '+=2px')
    })

    $(document).mouseup(function() {
        if(depressedButton) depressedButton.css('margin-top', '-=2px')
        depressedButton = null;
    })
})
```

Comment: Your solution is sexier :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a variable checking if you have clicked on the `div`. Then, if you didn't trigger `mouseup`, but you leave the `div` (`mouseleave` event), you do the same action as `mouseup`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clicked = false;

    $('#foo').mousedown(function() {
        clicked = true;
        $('#foo').css('margin-top', '+=2px');
    })

    $('#foo').mouseleave(function() {
        if(clicked)
            $('#foo').css('margin-top', '-=2px');
        clicked = false;
    })

    $('#foo').mouseup(function() {
        if(clicked)
            $('#foo').css('margin-top', '-=2px');
        clicked = false;
    })
})
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/dLwovpd9/2/

Comment: I went with this solution, but the 'sexier' one is a little more compact, so I am choosing that one. Thanks for the help